# Where is the hardware spec shown in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

Where is the spec for an instance displayed in Amazon AWS console?

I'm looking in EC2 console and I can't see anywhere that shows the hardware associated with an instance.

Comment: The "hardware spec?"  Do you mean things like amount of memory, number of cores, processor type?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, sorry. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon does now show this information from within the console. It shows you the server type (t1.micro, t2.small, etc), with that information you can go to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ and see what the system resource specifications are based on the instance type reported.